# Highlight image regions on hover with CSS

Tags: css, svg

What is the HTML CSS solution for highlighting specific areas of a map/floor plan like this?

http://www.centrecourtshopping.co.uk/store-info/

Comment: Do some research. Try it yourself. When you get stuck ask specific questions. Nobody is going to write documentation that is already all over the internet. Just google CSS hover and youll find tons of information on how to do it. If you want the hiding and showing of the Units like this site is showing youre going to have to use javascript too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use sprite image [look here](http://www.centrecourtshopping.co.uk/wp-content/themes/centrecourt/lib/images/upper-mall-sprite.png).

Basically, it works like that:

1. The map with dark-blue regions is completely static.
2. There is invisible layer on top of it made from small rectangular in their case `<a>` -- each corresponds to single dark-blue region and posses its its own `id`.
3. When cursor is placed over a rectangular with `id x` the sprite image is nicely aligned with its background (by setting CSS's `background-position`).

Do not think, this magic would be possible without using JavaScript.